# Makefile doesn't register dependencies in the right order

Tags: c++, build, makefile, gnu-make

I am writing a makefile for a project I'm working on in c++. I have a directory called tests which includes code for unit testing, amongst which are files that are using cxxtest.

The makefile is:

```
CC=clang++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11
LDFLAGS= -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lsfml-window
SOURCES=memtest.cpp guitest.cpp
CXXTEST=LTest.h
CXXCPP=$(CXXTEST:.h=.cpp)
CXXOBJ=$(CXXTEST:.h=.o)
CXXBIN=$(CXXTEST:.h=.bin)
MAX_PARALLEL=6
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
BINS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.b)

all: $(CXXBIN)

run: all


$(CXXCPP): $(subst .cpp,.h,$@)
cxxtestgen --error-printer -o $@ $(subst .cpp,.h,$@)


$(CXXOBJ): $(subst .o,.cpp,$@)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(subst .o,.cpp,$@)

$(CXXBIN): $(subst .bin,.o,$@) 
$(CC) $(subst .bin,.o,$@) $(OBJECTS) -o $@


$(OBJECTS): $(subst .o,.cpp,$@)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(subst .o,.cpp,$@) -o $@

$(BINS): $(subst .b,.o,$@)
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
clean:
rm -f LTest.cpp LTest LTest.o guitest guitest.o
```

However when I run `make LTest` where LTest.h exists, make is trying to run

```
  clang++ -c -Wall -std=c++11 -o LTest.o LTest.cpp
```

without making LTest.cpp first.

clearly, `$(subst .o,.cpp,$@)` expands into LTest.cpp, so why doesnt this work?

Comment: Keep in mind that I am a beginner at writing makefiles, so if there is a better way at doing what I'm trying to do I'd gladly hear it.

Comment: Could you post commands that you expect to be invoked? Your makefile is unusual, it is not clear what it tries to do.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic variables like `$@` are only meaningful in the recipe: `make` computes them *after* it parsed the dependency line completely. While interpreting the dependency `$@` is set to nothing. You have to spell it out explicitly:

```
$(CXXCPP): $(CXXTEST)
    cxxtestgen ... (this line may use $@, $^, etc)
```

Comment: Would that not, however, set every single other test as a dependency? Every time I'd change one test, every one of them would recompile.